# Great traffic for gendered pronoun question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-promotion

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/whats-the-modern-way-to-handle-gender-in-tech-writing) blows our standard traffic out of the water!

Does Lynn, or anybody else, know why that one question has got so much attention so quickly? Having gotten something right, we should do whatever-it-is more often :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff Atwood [earned the publicist badge](https://writers.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist?userid=84) for sharing it in [this rather ambiguous tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/76919395816976384) quoting from Neil Fein's comment under [the top-voted answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/whats-the-modern-way-to-handle-gender-in-tech-writing/2981#2981).  When high profile users of some service such as twitter or high profile bloggers share one of our questions it will drive traffic.

So if you have lots of followers, tweet our questions.

If you write a blog, blog about them.

If you can sway someone who can do these things, do.

Comment: see also -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/